# How do I connect a Spring Boot JAR to a remote Oracle database?

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-boot, database-connection

I have an application, using Spring 4.3.6 and Spring Boot 1.4.4, that is able to connect to an Oracle database via JNDI connection when deployed as a WAR to a WebLogic 12c server.

I now need to create a modified version of my existing project that can be exported as a standalone JAR with an embedded Tomcat server. How do I connect to the same database from within the JAR?

This is my current Eclipse directory for the current WAR application (with classpath `src`):

```
WAR Project
 |  src
 |   |  main.java
 |   |   |  controllers
 |   |   |   |  BasicController.java
 |   |   |   |  CrudController.java
 |   |   |  Application.java
 |   |  META-INF
 |   |   |  resources
 |   |   |   |  form.html
 |  JRE System Library [JDK 1.7]
 |  Referenced Libraries
 |  lib
 |   |  compile
 |   |  runtime
 |  resources
 |   |  application.properties
 |  target
 |  WEB-INF
 |   |  classes
 |   |  weblogic.xml
 |  build_war.xml
```

`build_war.xml` is the Ant build file for exporting the application to WAR. `form.html` is a static web page.

This is my existing code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
  return application.sources(Application.class);
  }
}

@Controller
public class BasicController {
  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String goToForm() {
    return "form.html";
  }
}

@RestController
public class CrudController {
  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @PostMapping("/result")
  public String sampleQuery(@RequestParam String tableName, @RequestParam String colNameSet,
      @RequestParam String valueSet) {
    String query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + colNameSet + ") VALUES " + valueSet;
    try {
      jdbcTemplate.update(query);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      query = e.toString();
    }
    return query;
  }
}
```

There is only one line in `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=database.jndi.name
```

The database URL is `jdbc:oracle:thin@ip-address:port-number:orcl`.

The application can connect to and update the database successfully as a WAR. What do I need to change to connect to the same database as a standalone JAR?

I cannot find any any references or tutorials on Google mentioning anything relevant to my problem. Please kindly walk me through what exactly I need to modify and how. Thanks!

**Edit**:

To add more information about this application: My Oracle database contains a table `PEOPLE` with the following columns:

```
ID  INT  NOT NULL,
NAME  VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
AGE  INT  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
```

`form.html` submits a POST request to `sampleQuery()` which then submits a database query from the form inputs.

When the application is deployed as WAR and connects to the database via JNDI, the database query is executed successfully.

However, after modifying `application.properties` as per shi's answer:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip-address:port:orcl
spring.datasource.username=user-name
spring.datasource.password=password
```

The following error is thrown when I run as Java Application within Eclipse:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID,NAME,AGE) VALUES ('2','Momo','21')]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PEOPLE
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:91)
...
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PEOPLE
...
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
...
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:408)
... 53 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PEOPLE
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
...
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
... 58 more
```

What happened?

Comment: That just gives me `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Comment: Please share your pom.xml or ant xml

Answer (score 0):

DataSource configuration is controlled by external configuration properties in spring.datasource.*. For example, you might declare the following section in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:thin://url:port/service
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.Oracle.OracleDriver
```

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: You didn't added the Oracle driver in the application.properties, to do that you need to add ojdbc7 jar in your classpath. But maven doesn't have Oracle driver in their repository.to add it manually please follow this:https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-oracle/